# Starting React and Nodemon backend in one NPM script

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, nodemon

I have a React app that depends on two backend NodeJS files that I run in my development environment using Nodemon.

I typically have to start up XAMPP, run each Node backend file, and start my React dev server. This gets a bit annoying and I'm trying to improve my setup.

I tried adding a new script to my `package.json` file:

```
"proj-start": "nodemon backend/proj-api.js; nodemon backend/proj-scrape.js; react-scripts start"
```

When I run this though, there are a few issues:

a) it doesn't actually run the exact command I've scripted. It runs this:

```
[nodemon] starting `react-scripts start backend/proj-api.js; nodemon backend/proj-scrape.js; react-scripts start`
```

So it seems to add an additional `react-scripts start` at the beginning for some reason.

b) It doesn't run the API. I'm guessing that's due to the added `react-scripts start` that's breaking my first scripted command.

c) Every time I save one of my backend files, it restarts the entire script rather than just the specific node application like Nodemon typically does.

Is what I'm attempting to accomplish not actually possible, or am I approaching it incorrectly?

Comment: Can you try something like `"proj-start": "nodemon --exec 'backend/proj-api.js & backend/proj-scrape.js' & react-scripts start"`
`

Comment: @Nick first try, `starting 'backend/bb-api.js` and `The system cannot find the path specified.` So it's picking up the quotation. I removed the quotations, and that randomly resulted in it opening up my old code editor ATOM which is apparently the default for .json files.